# Does VB.NET support Promises/Deferreds?

Tags: vb.net, deferred, promise

I'm interested in something similar to jQuery's Deferred object.  The below link seems to be  thread oriented.  With Javascript running in a single timeshared thread the model is quite different.

http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks

Comment: Are you familiar with delegates and events?  I'm not familiar with jQuery, but from what I just read, it sounds roughly equivalent to delegates and events (events are a special kind of delegate).

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC you can do async type stuff. Not exactly the same as the jQuery object. But I am not sure what the context is for your question. Here is link if this helps: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) available with .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012.  It builds on the infrastructure laid by the Task Parallel Library that is the topic of the link you provided above.

Comment: Looks to have promise (no pun intended).  I see they opted to expound upon the language rather than building asynchronous constructs from existing structures ala jQuery.

Comment: You can build something just like jQuery Deferred by using `Task`, `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`, `ConfigureAwait`, and of course `async` and `await`. E.g., see Stephen Toub's blog post on [implementing `then` with `await`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/15/implementing-then-with-await.aspx).